# I have a domain 'itcircle.net' which is hosted in 'freehosting.com'. Now i want to create a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My database name is "itcircle_s" user is "itcircle_ss"

Now I want to create a table name "simple_tb". 
But I failed. My code is like below:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("s",$con)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_tb(id int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,n varchar(40) ,PRIMARY KEY ( id ));",$con)){
    echo"TABLE created";
} else { 
    echo"Error creating database: ".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysqli_* functions annymore because they are deprecated and removed in PHP 7

Comment: My database name is "itcircle_s" user is "itcircle_ss"  hint check your mysql_connect function

Comment: Thanks Raymond Nijland

Comment: @RaymondNijland I hope you mean `mysql_*` functions ;)

Comment: oeps indeed i mean mysql_* functions are deprecated  and removed in PHP 7 @JonStirling little typing error

Comment: How i write $con

Comment: INT(255) - that's a pretty big number!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem on your script because you are using user 'root' to connect to it .

Check below : replace my_password with your password.

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","itcircle_ss","my_password","itcircle_s");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql=mysqli_query($con," your query goes here ");
```